# Custom Email is not sending on Order complete in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I am facing a problem to send a custom email in WooCommerce.

**Here is Error:**

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WC_Order as array in 
>   /home/wp-content/themes/structure/functions.php on line 548

My client want to send a custom email when everytime customer order and pay, besides the standard order confirmation email.

**Here is my code:**

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

function order_completed( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $to_email = $order["billing_address"];
    $headers = 'From: Your Name <your@email.com>' . "\r\n";
    wp_mail($to_email, 'subject', 'This is custom email', $headers );

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'order_completed' )
```

I also tried `"woocommerce_thankyou"` hook instead of `"woocommerce_payment_complete"` but is still not working.

I use Wordpress version is 4.5.2 and WooCommerce version is 2.6.1.

Comment: Woocommerce new order email  sending working ..?

Comment: email sending  by PHP mail() function  working..? or smtp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be there is a problem with: `$order->billing_address;`… So we can have a different approach getting the current user email *(not billing or shipping)* with `wp_get_current_user();` wordpress function. Then your code will be:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'order_completed_custom_email_notification' )
function order_completed_custom_email_notification( $order_id ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_email = $current_user->user_email;
    $to = sanitize_email( $user_email );
    $headers = 'From: Your Name <your@email.com>' . "\r\n";
    wp_mail($to, 'subject', 'This is custom email', $headers );
}
```

> You can test before `wp_mail()` function replacing `$user_email` by your email like this:
>
> ```
> wp_mail('your.mail@your-domain.tld', 'subject', 'This is custom email', $headers );
> ```
>
> If you get the mail, the problem was coming from `$to_email = $order->billing_address;`. 
> *(Try it also with `woocommerce_thankyou` hook too)*.

Last thing, you have to test all this on a hosted server, not with localhost on your computer. On localhost sending mails doesn't work in most cases…

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, thanks for your reply. Now error is gone but still not receiving email :( any idea?

Comment: I have tried woocommerce_thankyou but still not receiving email, I also checked spam folder

Comment: I am working on live server, if I add email address manually I am receiving email when add $user_email its not working

Comment: Its only work when I check Create an account? and enter password

Comment: Is that possible to send email without create an account ?

Answer (score 1):

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WC_Order as array in 
>   /home/wp-content/themes/structure/functions.php on line 548

This means that `$object` is an object and you need to use object notation such as `$object->billing_address` instead of array notation `$object['billing_address']`. The billing address object property will be defined when you call it by the magic `__get()` method of the `WC_Order` class, which really isn't very different from LoicTheAztec's approach above.

```
function order_completed( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $to_email = $order->billing_address;
    $headers = 'From: Your Name <your@email.com>' . "\r\n";
    wp_mail($to_email, 'subject', 'This is custom email', $headers );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'order_completed' );
```